# how to add to cart a product with a value multiplied by some amount.?

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop

i am new to prestashop. here i want to add to cart a product with its value multiplied by some amount.
such as, my product's value per meter is $200. user will put height and width in meter. if a user inputs 2m height and 2 meter width, then the calculated value will be $200*2*2 = $800

i want to add to cart this product with $800 instead of $200 per quantity through ajax. how is it possible.![image: here is height and width each 2m.][here is height and width each 1m.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXhln.jpg)

Comment: I would implement a HTML form, where user specifies requested dimensions and e.g. Javascript function to compute amount of the product (e.g. square meter) and insert it to Prestashop's amount input. Rest of the job will do Prestashop controller when user clicks on "Add to cart" button. The template you have to change is `product.tpl` in your theme folder.

Comment: hi @klimpond, thanks for posting. "insert it to Prestashop's amount input"->  please tell me how to do this job.? waiting for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Locate the `product.tpl` file in your theme folder. There is an `<input id="quantity_wanted">` element. You need to update this value according to user input of the product width and height.

Adding to cart will be handled by Prestashop, as it sends `{id_product, quantity, id_product_attribute, ...}` to the PHP controller, where quantity is value of "quantity_wanted" input.

So, add two HTML `<input>` elements for width and height and process these values using Javascript, which will change "quantity_wanted" input value.

Also think of: providing this functionality inside a module to avoid changing Prestashop core code, storing width and height of each added product, as you will need this information to prepare customer order.

Comment: I would recommend using Firebug to locate elements in Prestashop templates.